Is "No. You won't." used as double entendre?
In Bullet Train (2022), The Elder sits across from Ladybug and
Prince:

Ladybug (to The Elder): Okay, fella, you're creepin' me out. So, if
you don't mind, could you just find another seat, like, way, way, way
down there? And that way, I won't have to tell you twice.
The Elder: No. You won't.
After hearing The Elder’s response, Ladybug gets up from the seat to sit elsewhere.

Is "No. You won't." used as double entendre ?

What second meaning do you think you are hearing?

Yes, what exactly?

There's a significant pause after "The Elder" says "No". It's got its own line in my subtitle file, followed 2 seconds later by "You won't". Clearly No there is a refusal to move, and You won't is spoken threateningly, implying dire consequences will follow if "Ladybug" is bold/foolish enough to repeat his request. So there is a sense of "ambiguity" ("No, I won't move", and "No, and you'd better not dare to ask me again!"), but I wouldn't call it "double entendre", because that invariably implies a second sexually charged meaning, which isn't the case here.

@Lambie: No. Like I said, these are two separate utterances. Initial No means No, I can't find another seat, because I'm not going to move. But You won't means You won't ask me again if you know what's good for you. But Brad Pitt / Ladybug does know what's good for him - so he sighs and says to his companion "Let's just move".

My example was bad. But I do not think two or one utterance makes a difference. Also, there's no link so this question does not have enough context. It could also be: Yeah, I get it, bitch

I think the OP has misunderstood what a double entendre means. There is no context about what is visually happening in the film, so based on dialogue alone there is nothing provocative or suggestive at all in the Elder's response. Maybe the OP was thinking of threat or ellipsis as in "No (I am not moving from my seat). You won't. (you won't tell me a second time to get up)

"Double entendre" means that something has two meanings. Usually this means one innocent meaning and one meaning that is sexually suggestive. For example, there's a classic line, "If I said you had a beautiful body, would you hold it against me?" One interpretation is that the speaker means, "would you be angry with me?" The other is that he means it literally, "would you press your body against mine?"
In this case ... I haven't seen the movie, but from your quote, I don't see a likely double meaning, certainly not a sexual one. "Ladybug" asks "the Elder" to move to another seat, and says that she doesn't want to have to make this request twice. He refuses to move, and then says "you won't". Presumably meaning, you won't make the request twice or you won't have to make the request twice. Which sounds like a restrained threat: you won't dare to ask me again, or some negative consequences will result. Without having seen the movie, I can't give any further detail about what I think anyone means.

I doubt OP misunderstands what a double entendre means, but I think there's a case for saying You won't here kinda has two meanings. The real meaning is unquestionably Don't you dare to ask me again! (Which I know you won't do, because that would be suicide). But given the antecedent, if the speaker had delivered those words while standing up to move as requested, we'd just interpret the threatening tone as "I'll take revenge on you later for humiliating me like this". Where the "surface reading" of You won't [have to ask again] would be significantly different.

@FumbleFingers Well, I haven't seen the movie, so I can't speak to context. It seems unlikely to me from the quoted sentences that "the Elder" was getting up to move as he said it. First from the fact that he said "no", second because it says that Ladybug then moved. But it's pointless to speculate about what may or may not have happened in a movie I didn't see. Could one imagine some context in which "you won't" would have a double meaning? Sure.

There could be a double entendre, although without further context it is difficult to say what that second meaning is.
Although 'double entendre' literally just means that there are two meanings or interpretations of something, in common use, it tends to imply the second meaning is sexually suggestive. I can't tell if that is the case here as I don't get the relationship between the characters or what has been said before.
At face value though, the response seems to provide a literal response to the previous statement "I won't have to tell you twice", as if the Elder is agreeing. But the saying "you don't have to tell/ask me twice" does tend to mean that the person will quickly and willingly agree to something, and that could be a sexual advance.

"that could be a sexual advance"? If you had access to the movie fragment, you couldn't possibly think that. If you don't, why post an answer?

@FumbleFingers Answer this. If you don't answer this then I know you're just being hypercritical as usual. Does this site exist to (a) answer questions about specific movies by providing detailed breakdowns of context, subtext, character development etc, OR (b) answer questions about English which will stand to perpetuity and help future language learners who have the same or similar questions?

That's a ridiculous digression. The thing being asked about here is effectively entirely concerned with the meaning of three spoken words. More specifically, with a significant pause not reflected by the OP's transcription. Guessing at possible meanings is pointless if you don't know at least how those words were delivered (ideally, also some knowledge of the characters and plot). Assuming the OP actually understands what "double-entendre" means, he should be steered well away from that irrelevant line of enquiry for this specific case.

@FumbleFingers Noted that you did not answer the question.
